# Boxplot in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm new to R and have been trying to make a boxplot. A part of the data I'm using is shown

```
            h1          h2          h3          h4          h5          h6          h7          h8          h9         h10
1  0.003719430 0.002975544 0.003049933 0.003421876 0.003421876 0.003347487 0.003645042 0.003496264 0.007364472 0.009075410
2  0.003400540 0.002749373 0.003038781 0.003328188 0.003328188 0.003400540 0.003472892 0.003400540 0.007741656 0.009333398
3  0.003741387 0.002918282 0.003142765 0.003367248 0.003367248 0.003367248 0.003666559 0.003516904 0.008081396 0.008156223
4  0.003870634 0.002884002 0.003187581 0.003339370 0.003567055 0.003415265 0.003794739 0.003491160 0.008348426 0.007741268
5  0.003782963 0.002950711 0.003177689 0.003480326 0.003404667 0.003404667 0.003707304 0.003631645 0.008927793 0.007414608
6  0.003643736 0.002884624 0.003264180 0.003416002 0.003491913 0.003416002 0.003871469 0.003795558 0.009033428 0.007135649
7  0.003718600 0.003035592 0.003111482 0.003339151 0.003566821 0.003566821 0.003642710 0.003870380 0.008120209 0.008044319
8  0.003819313 0.002979064 0.003284609 0.003360995 0.003590154 0.003437382 0.003895699 0.003590154 0.008326102 0.007791398
9  0.003899334 0.002981844 0.003211216 0.003364131 0.003669961 0.003440589 0.003746419 0.003669961 0.008410328 0.007569295
10 0.003828488 0.002986220 0.003292499 0.003445639 0.003522209 0.003522209 0.003598778 0.003598778 0.008422673 0.007810115
```

When I use the default `boxplot` command then this is what I get

```
boxplot(df)
```

[image]

I have been trying to generate the boxplot for same data using `ggplot2` but it gives an error which I am unable to resolve. Here's what I tried.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- readRDS('data.Rda')
ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot()
```

Here's the error

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:df[, 6:15]
```

I saw the [ggplot2 docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_boxplot.html) for `geom_boxplot` and realize (from the example) that I need to rearrange my data like

```
col1        col2
h1   0.003719430
h1   0.003400540
h1   0.003741387
h1   0.003870634
h1   0.003782963
h1   0.003643736
h2   0.002975544
h2   0.002749373
h2   0.002918282
h2   0.002884002
h2   0.002950711
h2   0.002884624
...
```

and use something like

```
ggplot(df, aes(factor(col1), col2)) + geom_boxplot()
```

But that is a lot of work. I believe that there must be some way to do this automatically which I'm not able to find. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nope that's the gist of it. That's the downside to `ggplot2`. Much more verbose. But also much easier to make very pretty.

Comment: ...and you probably spent 10x more time writing this question that the "work" involved in reshaping your data: `library(reshape2); melt(df)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right `ggplot` requires your data to be reshaped, but it isn't that hard using the package `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(df)
ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot()
```